# How to install windows phone 8 sdk on windows 7 maallchine

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, .net-4.5

I would like to know if it is possible to install the windows phone 8 sdk one a workstation that has windows 7 OS?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like a no.

See Requirements here : [WP8 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

---

> •Supported Operating System
> Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro 
> •Operating system type:
> Windows 8 64-bit (x64) client versions
>
> •Hardware:
> 6.5 GB of free hard disk space
> 4 GB RAM
> 64-bit (x64) CPU
>
> •Windows Phone 8 Emulator:
> Windows 8 Pro edition or greater
> Requires a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)
>
> If your computer meets the hardware and operating system requirements, but does not meet the requirements for the Windows Phone 8 Emulator, the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 will install and run. However, the Windows Phone 8 Emulator will not function and you will not be able to deploy or test apps on the Windows Phone 8 Emulator.

---

On a side note, you can always run it on a VM that is Windows 8 :D